# Error in package: sp when starting RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

When starting RStudio the following message appears: `Loading required package: sp.` I try to install the sp package and the message appears:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘sp’ is in use and will not be installed
```

That way, I can not install it. Also, because of this error, I'm having trouble calling the `dplyr` package. How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```
detach("package:sp", unload = TRUE)
install.packages("sp", dependencies=TRUE)
```

Comment: I had to install again. Thank you.